# How can I disable 'httpErrors' on the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I have such a setting, but what should I do to disable this setting on a controller?

```
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
        <clear />
        <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Core/Code/400" />
        <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Core/Code/403" />
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Core/Code/404" />
        <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Core/Code/500" />
    </httpErrors>
```

When `existingResponse="Auto"` the code below works, but in this case my error pages are not displayed.

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

I want it to work on either side. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your controller is calling. Secod you can try this in web.config,

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
```